# Is it possible to change the value of the identifier `eval` from within strict code?

Tags: javascript, theory

One of the guarantees that strict mode provides is that in strict function code, the identifier `arguments` always refers to that function's Arguments object.

```
function fn () { 
    'use strict';

    // malicious code

    arguments // still refers to the function's Arguments object
}
```

So, no matter what code is injected at `// malicious code`, the `arguments` identifier is immutably bound to the function's Arguments object during the entire function invocation.

I was wondering if the same guarantees are provided for the `eval` identifier, i.e. does the `eval` identifier with guarantee refer to the built-in global `eval` function at all times?

I'd like to point out that the above mentioned guarantee is *not* provided if our strict code is nested within non-strict code. Non-strict code is allowed to create local `"eval"` bindings, or to mutate the global `"eval"` binding. (Also, if another non-strict program uses the same global object (as in a web-page containing multiple scripts), the above mentioned guarantee is also not provided.)

So, for the sake of this question, I'd like to define the following scenario:

- our program is stand-alone, i.e. it doesn't share its global object with any other program,
- our program consists of a single strict IIFE, like so:

  ```
  (function () {
      'use strict';

      // malicious code

      eval // does it still refer to the built-in global eval function? 

  }());
  ```

Given these conditions, is it possible to inject code at `\\ malicious code`, that will change the value of the `eval` identifier?

Comment: I assume you're already aware that the answer is "no" and are just looking for a reference. ;)

Comment: @GGG Based on my research, the answer is "no", but I'm learning new things about JavaScript every day, so it wouldn't surprise me if it were possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically it should not be possible to reassign the `eval` identifier to something other than the `eval` property of the global object, or mask it with a local variable, according to annex C:

> The identifier eval or arguments may not appear as the LeftHandSideExpression of an Assignment operator (11.13) or of a PostfixExpression (11.3) or as the UnaryExpression operated upon by a Prefix Increment (11.4.4) or a Prefix Decrement (11.4.5) operator.

...

> It is a SyntaxError if the Identifier "eval" or the Identifier "arguments" occurs as the Identifier in a PropertySetParameterList of a PropertyAssignment that is contained in strict code or if its FunctionBody is strict code (11.1.5).

...

> It is a SyntaxError if the identifier eval or arguments appears within a FormalParameterList of a strict mode FunctionDeclaration or FunctionExpression (13.1)

...and so on.

---

As discussed below, it's possible to change the global eval function by assigning a new value to that property of the global object. A reference to the global object can be obtained by an indirect call to `eval` in strict mode:

```
var glob = (0,eval)('this');
```

You could extend that to something that will work reliably in non-strict mode as well:

```
var glob = (function(){ return this || (0,eval)('this') }());
```

...and then assign its `eval` property to something else.

While `eval` will still be identical to the `eval` property of the global object, it won't be the built-in `eval` anymore, which should meet your conditions.

Comment: One thing that I didn't mention in my question is that, had the function from my question access to the global object (and it has not in my scenario), it would be able to change the value of `eval` by assigning to `globalObject.eval`. So, for instance, were the function invoked via `.call(this)` (passing in the global object), instead of `()`, then this code `this.eval = null;` would change the value of `eval`, so, later on, `eval // => null`. It's things like this, that make me ask for confirmation on SO.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yeah, I was wondering if you were aware of that... in a browser you could just do `window.eval = /* hacks */` from anywhere, that would probably be the approach to take if you wanted to mess with eval. Note the difference in strict mode between direct and indirect eval calls, though.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot that, in browsers, a function doesn't have to worry about retrieving a reference to the global object, since such a reference is omnipresent via `window`. So, no matter how strict our code is, it is always possible to destroy the built-in `eval` function by assigning to `window.eval`. That's certainly a loophole in strict mode. Making the global `"eval"` binding immutable would have fixed that, but this change wasn't made to prevent legacy programs from breaking (I assume, that's the reason). What a pity.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes, but even in strict mode you can always get a reference to the global object (through indirect eval, ironically). `[eval][0]('this')` returns the global object in strict mode (kangax found this).

Comment: Are you aware that you've just answered my question? By injecting `[eval][0]('this').eval = null;` into my example, it is possible to change the value of `eval`. So, it *is* possible.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, yes, but it doesn't meet the condition in your comment: `does it still refer to the built-in global eval function?` They are still identical to each other; they have both changed.

Comment: Once `[eval][0]('this').eval = null;` executes, the built-in `eval` function is gone... it doesn't exist anymore. `eval` will still refer to the global `"eval"` binding, but the value of that binding isn't the `eval` function anymore. My request was to change the value of `eval` (so that it doesn't refer to the built-in `eval` function anymore) - this has been accomplished. Notice how my question doesn't require that `eval` refers to a local `"eval"` binding (a binding of the function's lexical environment) - it can still refer to the global `"eval"` binding.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas gotcha, for some reason I read that as you wanting to mask it with a local variable. So I understood your question wrong, it's possible after all. Updated :)

Comment: I've done some additional research on indirect eval. First of all, `[eval][0]` throws in Safari, and Opera. However, that doesn't mean that those browsers don't support indirect eval... it just happens to be a problematical expression for those browsers, since a different expression, `(1,eval)` works fine. Second, the behavior of this type of indirect eval doesn't depend on strict mode - it produces the same result in ES Default vs ES Strict.

Comment: And third, I've found that an indirect eval via `(1,eval)` evaluates in global scope in all relevant browsers (FF, Ch, O, S, IE7/8/9), which means that the expression `(1,eval)('this')` will retrieve the global object in every browser, in every context (strict, or non-strict).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas thanks for pointing this out! Juiry originally suggested `(0,eval)` but I've used `[eval][0]` in a few places to pacify linters... luckily none of it was code for the web, I think.

Comment: What does `[eval][0]` throw in Safari and Opera, by the way? This sounds like a browser bug.

Comment: In Opera: *"EvalError: eval called with invalid this object"*. I don't have Safari here on my notebook, but it was something similar...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas weird, I just tried it too, I think I'll make a question about this... they seem to be doing that intentionally. Throws the same error for `({a:eval}).a('this')`.

Comment: Btw, kangax created a [test-page](http://kangax.github.com/jstests/indirect-eval-testsuite/). Opera throws in 6 cases. I've no idea what rules govern this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No, not as far as i can tell, you cannot overwrite the native eval function in strict mode. The code below would give the following error. `SyntaxError: Assignment to eval or arguments is not allowed in strict mode`

```
(function () {
   'use strict';
   eval = function(){ console.log('eval invoked'); }  
   eval();  
}());
```

Comment: We've established that it *can* be done. See comment section of GGG's answer.